# Making a trading card game XNA

Tags: xna-4.0, playing-cards

I was wanting to make a trading card game using xna 4.0 I was wondering if anyone could lead me in the right direction to any information or tutorials that would help me make that game.

Comment: I feel that this question is way to vague. Just start with the tutorials that are provided with XNA and direct more specific questions here after trying to solve them yourself.

Comment: Have you considered using Silverlight? Unless you intend to have lots of animations and 3D models, or release the game on Xbox, XNA is not a good alternative for interface heavy games with static screens.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the [Beginner XNA 4.0 Tutorials](http://xnagpa.net/xna4tutorials.php)

Note:You need to have some C# experience

Answer (score 0):

This site has a few tutorials to learn the basics
 http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials.shtml

And dont forget the official site
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203894(v=XNAGameStudio.40).aspx